# How to get info from filesystem matched line?

Tags: javascript, filesystems

Hello I use filesystem in my .js and I want to get id from line that match username.
Example: 
**database.txt**

```
[{id:"0",username:"blabla1"},{id:1, username:"blabla2}]
```

how can I get id from username blabla**1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a litte typo in your code (" missing).

You can access attributes like this:

```
a=[{id:"0",username:"blabla1"},{id:1, username:"blabla2"}];
console.log(a[0].id);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eLt1bq71/